# WHERE clause on one of two parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

A table has sequence numbers and timestamps and other data.
A stored procedure takes 2 parameters, and the user can pass in a null sequence number.

This is what I am trying to achieve but it doesn't work (SQL says Incorrect syntax near >)

```
create proc dbo.MyProc( @SequenceNo int, @Timestamp datetime ) as
begin
  select * from MyTable where
        case when @SequenceNo is not null THEN SequenceNo > @SequenceNo
              ELSE Timestamp > @Timestamp
        end
end
```

How to do this?

Comment: I have but I thought it would be standard SQL

Comment: In place of assigning value in ' THEN ' part , why are you checking expression for greater than ?, You can assign a true false , 1 or 0 , or any other value of your choice here

Comment: It is supposed to mean that when &SequenceNo is not null then use this as the basis for the condition, otherwise use Timestamp. SequenceNo > &SequenceNo should return a condition of true or false. If false, I want this row skipped, I don't want to try further cases. (replace & with you know what)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below. It uses a case statement in where clause:

```
declare proc.MyProc( @SequenceNo int, @Timestamp datetime ) as
begin
  select * 
  from MyTable 
  where
        1 = case 
                when @SequenceNo is not null and SequenceNo > @SequenceNo then 1
                when @SequenceNo is null and Timestamp > @Timestamp then 1
                else 0
            end
end
```

Comment: Something like what I was looking for but doesn't work. Looks like second when needs to also check @SequenceNo is null.

Comment: I see, so it only check for Timestamp when the @SequenceNo is null. I have updated the query.

Comment: Yes this works. I'm not 100% happy with it still because really I'd like "not null" to be the first case and it then returns something true or false dependent on the second condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like SQL Server (although this doesn't make a difference to the answer).  In general, it is best to leave `CASE` expressions out of `WHERE` clauses and to just use boolean logic:

```
select t.*
from MyTable t
where (@SequenceNo is not null and SequenceNo > @SequenceNo) or
      (@SequenceNo is null and Timestamp > @Timestamp);
```

Because `NULL` values fail all comparisons, you can simplify this to:

```
select t.*
from MyTable t
where (SequenceNo > @SequenceNo) or
      (@SequenceNo is null and Timestamp > @Timestamp);
```

And, in case you want to pass in *both* values and have filtering, perhaps this is useful:

```
select t.*
from MyTable t
where (SequenceNo > @SequenceNo or @SequenceNo is null) and
      (Timestamp > @Timestamp or @Timestamp is null);
```

It is not the same logic, but quite possibly what you want.

Comment: The last one may be useful, but does not of course return the same as the other two in all cases.

Comment: This is probably good enough for what I need. In the real query there is more logic in the select, i.e. a few joins, so I don't want 2 procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE Statement in below format :

```
DECLARE proc dbo.MyProc( @SequenceNo int, @Timestamp datetime ) as
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM MyTable 
    WHERE SequenceNo = CASE WHEN ( @SequenceNo IS NOT NULL OR SequenceNo > 
         @SequenceNo ) THEN @SequenceNo ELSE SequenceNo END
         AND Timestamp  = CASE WHEN @SequenceNo IS NULL AND Timestamp >  
      @Timestamp THEN @Timestamp ELSE Timestamp  END 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Dynamic Query Like This

```html
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
( 
  @SequenceNo int, @Timestamp datetime 
)
 AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL Nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = N'select * from MyTable where'

IF @SequenceNo IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N' SequenceNo > @SequenceNo';
 END
ELSE 
  BEGIN
     SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N' Timestamp > @Timestamp';
   END  

EXEC( @SQL)
END
```